# How do I make this Loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

So here are the directions for this step in my program: 
Create a loop that traverses through the dice list.
Inside the loop add one to the appropriate index value in the counts list for each value in the dice list.  When the loop is done, the counts list should have the number of times each value occurs in the dice list. Heres what I have:

```
# Step 1
from random import randint

class Dice(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dice = []
        x = 0
        while x < 5:
            self.dice.append(str(randint(1,6)))
            x += 1

hand = Dice() # Creates a Dice object
print hand.dice # Prints the instance variable dice (5 random numbers)


# Step 2
class Dice(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dice = []

    def roll(self,how_many):
        for i in range(how_many):
            self.Dice.append(randint(1,6))

hand.roll = ([0,2,3]) # Change the numbers in index positions 0, 2, and 3.
print hand.dice # Prints the instance variable dice (5 random numbers)

#Step 3
def score(self):
    self.counts = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for i in range(counts):
        index + 1
        print i
```

Comment: Why is the class Dice declared twice? This should not even run in python.

Comment: Just a general comment. In your `__init__()` for Step 1, a more pythonic way to do your `self.dice.append()` would be as `for _ in xrange(6): self.dice.append(str(randint(1, 6)))` (splitting it to a second line after the `:`, of course).  This does away with initializing and incrementing a counter variable (`x`).

Comment: Are you actually building a histogram? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram

Answer (score 0):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> lst = [4, 4, 5, 2, 6]
>>> counts = [0] * 7
>>> for i, e in enumerate(lst):
...     counts[e] += 1
...
>>> print counts
[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1]
```